# How do you grab an article including the links in a usable format?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I have an internal deployment of mediawiki. In some articles are external links. I have another page that makes API calls to the wiki to pull articles into another website. When I pull those articles in, links do not get pulled in properly. Here is an example.

Wiki article:

`Use [http://example.com THIS LINK] to contact the vendor.`

API URL:

`https://mysite.com/mediawiki/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=Vendor`

API results:

`Use THIS LINK to contact the vendor.`

Notice the link is completely stripped away. I've also tried to add my own html into mediawiki for links but mediawiki escapes < and > symbols and so the API see's '&lt' and '&gt'. Also mediawiki displays html and not an actual link.

How do I make mediawiki API calls and keep link information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you can use `action=parse` instead. The query would look like this:

```
https://mysite.com/mediawiki/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Vendor&prop=text
```