# How to embed MediaWiki page content into my site?

Tags: html, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Our corporate wiki is Mediawiki. I have no problem to put **iframe** into my site to refer for some article on wiki.

But my own site have a lot of widgets and own style. I don't want to include Mediawiki navigation/search/login widgets, logo image.

Is it possible and how to get Mediawiki page contents without widgets (only article body)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. You'll probably want to use the `action=render` url parameter, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=render&title=Main_Page. Note that the stylesheets from the wiki aren't included, so you'll need to copy the relevant rules to your site's css files. See also [this](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:FAQ#get_the_content_of_a_page_.28HTML.29.3F).

Answer (score 1):

Thank waldir for answer!

After asking question I perform own research and end with code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState !== 4) {
            console.log("Not ready, code: %o", httpRequest.readyState);
            return;
        }
        if (httpRequest.status !== 200) {
            console.log("Server error: %o", httpRequest.status);
            return;
        }
        var json = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        console.log("json: %o", json);
        var wiki = json.query.pages["1"].revisions[0]["*"];
        console.log("wiki: %o", wiki);
        var html = InstaView.convert(wiki);
        console.log("html: %o", html);
        document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = html;
    };
    var url = 'https://wiki.evil-company.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&format=json&titles=Main_page&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content';
    httpRequest.open('GET', url, true);
    httpRequest.send(null);
}
```

Here I use https://github.com/cscott/instaview/blob/master/main.js project which is enhanced http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Pilaf to transform **json** output to **HTML** on browser side.

The reason for this code because our wiki is old or misconfigured and **action=render** is not available. But I trap into cross-domain scripting issue so I think that **iframe** with **action=render** is better solution.

See also [How do you grab an article including the links in a usable format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067832/how-do-you-grab-an-article-including-the-links-in-a-usable-format)

Another suggestion to use **action=parse** (http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&title=Linux) lead to warning:

```
You are looking at the HTML representation of the XML format.
HTML is good for debugging, but is unsuitable for application use.
Specify the format parameter to change the output format.
```

**UPDATE**

Perfect solution just append query **action=render** to any valid wiki URL like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux?action=render

Comment: You may be able to get around the cross-domain issues using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which the MediaWiki API [supports](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests) via the `callback` parameter. As for `action=parse`, you still need to [specify the format you want](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests), e.g. with `format=json`.

Comment: Also, just to make sure, you _do_ know that `action=render` is _not_ a valid `api.php` action, but should instead be passed as [a parameter to `index.php`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Actions), right? (Yes, it's kind of confusing that both of those scripts take a parameter with the same name and a similar purpose, but different allowed values.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Many thanks for **?action=render**! I really don't know about it. I work perfect, just add to the end of any valid wiki page!